# Zxing 'undefined symbols for architecture x86-x64' error

Tags: xcode, linker, zxing

I use `zxing` lib in my `OS X` application. I've included `zxing-objc` to my project and simply copy-pasted code from zxing demo (`zxing-root/objc/examples/demo`) to the separate `ViewController` class. When trying to compile project, I get the following linker errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_QTCaptureDevice", referenced from:
     objc-class-ref in ScanViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ZXCapture", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ScanViewController.o
  "_QTMediaTypeMuxed", referenced from:
      -[ScanViewController performVideoSourceScan] in ScanViewController.o
  "_QTMediaTypeVideo", referenced from:
      -[ScanViewController performVideoSourceScan] in ScanViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've carefully checked all code and compared my project properties (including c++ compiler options) to demo project properties, and everything is done right.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the necessary frameworks to your app target. You can look in the sample app for an example. Select the target in Xcode, select Build Phases, and open the Link With Libraries entry. You'll see that it includes both QuartzCore and zxing-objc-framework. It sounds like you don't have those in your project.